# WordPress - Insert content after first post in Loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I've set up PHP code to insert a list of Categories **after the first post** on a WordPress Home page displaying posts.

It's working fine.

My problem is, I want to display a heading above the list, maybe a HTML H3 tag with the text "Browse our categories" or whatever.

My problem is, **where do I place this HTML heading**??

If I place it within the **div tag** (see code below) the heading is repeated down the page, below every other post. I only want it to appear once - after the first post, just above my list of categories.

I have tried making it part of the $output variable, for example:

```
 $output = '<h3>Browse Categories</h3>';
 $output .= '<a class="cat-links" href=" ... etc.
```

but that doesn't work.

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php get_template_part('content', get_theme_mod('solopine_home_layout')); ?>

<?php // CUSTOM CODE TO DISPLAY LIST OF CATEGORIES ?>

<div style="text-align:center; padding-bottom:100px;">

<?php 
if( $wp_query->current_post == 0 ) { 

    $allowed = array(17,18,19,20);
    $categories = get_categories(array(
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'parent'  => 0,
        'hide_empty'=> true,
        'include' => $allowed,
        )
        );

    $separator = ' ';
    $output = '';

    if($categories){

    foreach($categories as $category) {

    $output .= '<a class="cat-links" href="'.get_category_link( $category ).'" title="' .        
    esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ),            $category->name ) ) . '">'.$category- 
    >cat_name.'</a>';
        }
        echo trim($output);

    }

} 

?>      

</div>

<?php // END CUSTOM CODE ?> 

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Hoping someone can help.

Thanks,

Mekong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it before foreach loop. `echo '<h3>Browse Categories</h3>';`